# 2 quickies about NSNotification Center

Tags: objective-c

In all the tutorials or examples I find, they show a colon after the selector name (`getCurrentData:`), like so:

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         addObserver:self
         selector:@selector(getCurrentData:)
         name:@"mapsReceived"
         object:nil ];`

Since there is nothing after this colon in the examples, I assume that the method specified does not take any arguments. And mine doesn't either, but when I use the above syntax my app crashes and says `unrecognized selector sent to instance` I remove the colon, and it works. So why do all examples show a colon?

Secondly, if I *did* use a selector that required an argument, how can I do that? If I do this:

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(createButtons:@"ten grand";)
     name:@"mapsReceived"
     object:nil ];`

It won't even compile; I get tons of errors until I remove the text string and the colon. Yet I can call this method, with the string, just fine when using it outside NSNotification. Is there a way to do what I want here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, most all examples assume that you are passing the notification to the method.  For example:

```
- (void)respondToNotification:(NSNotification *);
```

This would be represented as:

```
@selector(respondToNotification:)
```

If you removed this argument, it would be

```
@selector(respondToNotification)
```

As for the second item, you cannot specify arguments in that manner.  You need to architect your methods in such a way that it receives the notification as the argument, and then you can inspect the notification and call another method to perform whatever action you need.

Answer (score 2):

When the `NSNotificationCenter` sends a notification (via the selector you specify - eg `getCurrentData:`), it will  pass an instance of `NSNotification`, so your method must accept a single argument which is such an instance.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: You "must" not, you "should". Must implies it doesn't compile, which it does. Should implies if you're doing another way, you're doing it wrong... which is true. +1'd you though :D

Comment: It may compile, but from the docs linked above: "Selector that specifies the message the receiver sends notificationObserver to notify it of the notification posting. The method specified by notificationSelector must have one and only one argument (an instance of NSNotification)." +1 appreciated, though :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the first question is that in Objective C the colon is part of the function name. If you omit it you refer to a different function, one that doesn't take any parameters. However, notifications methods are always called with (and must therefore accept) one parameter: the Notification object:

Here is an excerpt of the [NSNotificationCenter Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

"The method specified by notificationSelector must have one and only one argument (an instance of NSNotification)"

Answer (score 1):

If there is a colon at the end then it takes a parameter. You do not pass it anything in the `@selector` call. Your first example is correct and your `getCurrentData:` method should look like this.

```
-(void)getCurrentData:(NSNotification*)note
{
     //Implementation
}
```

For each colon you see in a selector that is how parameters it takes, for example both `@selector(aMethod:secondArg:thirdArg:)` and `@selector(aMethod:::)` have different signatures but both would take 3 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying ti add an observer and send a message in the same code, it doesn't work that way.
You declare that THIS method is used to react to an event as in [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMethod:) name:@"behaviorName" object:nil];

Then it will be called when the event happens, and you can pass it a special object via the object parameter to work on. However, behind the colon is supposed to be passed a special event encapsulation  object (NSNotification obviously), see the documentation, which you are supposed to design your myMethod: method for. If you omitted the object in your method code, then it makes sense trying to call it fails, since you're calling another method, in effect an overload :p